# Getting "Have you authenticated with Twitter" using Fabric and using Twitter API Client

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to create a recyclerview of tweets using Fabric. But every time i try to create an TwitterApiClient after authenticating using Fabric all i get is an error with "Have you Authenticated with Twitter?" Here's the code.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = Twitter.getApiClient();
    StatusesService statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
    statusesService.userTimeline(null, "rickygervais", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> listResult) {
                    Log.i(TWITTER_USER_TIMELINE_REQUEST, "Successfully retrieved tweets");
                    feedAdapter.updateItems(listResult.data);
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                    Log.e(TWITTER_USER_TIMELINE_REQUEST, e.toString());
                }
            });
}
```

Please tell me i'm being a moron and missing something obvious.

**UPDATE**

This is the line where i am getting the error message

```
TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = Twitter.getApiClient();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TwitterApiClient requires a Session in order to make Twitter API calls.

Take a look at the documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login

Also, to use guest authentication on android, be sure to update to the latest version of the SDK, 1.3.0.

Comment: This clears up why i was having this problem: https://twittercommunity.com/t/receiving-must-have-valid-session-did-you-authenticate-with-twitter-on-android-when-trying-to-get-a-user-timeline/31523/4?u=dumonkri

Answer (score 0):

Your statusesService line is incorrect.

You have

```
statusesService.userTimeline(null, "rickygervais", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
```

Should be

```
statusesService.userTimeline(session.getId(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
```

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline

Comment: Actually, this won't solve my issue. I'm getting the error when getting the Twitter API Client: TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = Twitter.getApiClient();

Comment: Hmmmm odd. I'm on mobile but take a look at my current project and maybe you can find how to fix it.  

https://github.com/joeythomaschaske/SocialCleanUp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/jpt3/socialcleanup

Comment: This looks to be the culprit. 

            final TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();

Comment: Didn't solve it for me either unfortunately, i'm so confused?!

Comment: Contact fabric at support@fabric.io about it. They're pretty good at getting back to you with answers